# Node.js, express.js & hogan.js: partials not loading correctly after second refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hogan.js

I have an express 3 application running good, but there is something going wrong when i refresh the site for the second time.

```
var x = {footer:"footer", header:"header"}

exports.index = function(req, res){

    res.render("index.html", {jow: "ieps", partials:x})

}
```

When i go to my site for the first time then all is fine and all partials render great.

**But when refreshing i have this error:**

```
Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/kevinvanhove/Documents/work/projects/basing/business/klanten/javascript/nodeJS/express/basing/views/<h2>wow</h2>.html'
```

However, when removing the x variable and adding the object literal directly to the res.render parameter list all works fine again.

```
exports.index = function(req, res){

    res.render("index.html", {jow: "ieps", partials:{footer:"footer", header:"header"}})
```

}

**UPDATE: index.html view**

```
{{> header}}
<h1>jow en {{jow}}</h1>
{{> footer}}
```

See this vine for a quick overview:

https://vine.co/v/M7BYi75pdrh

Some insight would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It looks like you modify either `partials` (inside view file), or `x` after it was declared.

Comment: I think this is simple closure problem, since the code above is in a  module (index.js) that i include in app.js using require(). The res.render function must change the values of the partial keys. That should explain why, on the second refresh, the footer:"footer" changes to the contents of the footer.html page. Can someone elaborate on that? Thx...

Comment: Could you post your view?

Comment: added the view to my post

Comment: Can you please post a code with `<h2>wow</h2>` fragment? It seems that you wrote something like this: `...header = '<h2>wow</h2>'`

Comment: Consolitate.js alters the original object: https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/blob/master/lib/consolidate.js#L124

Answer (score 0):

Like commented above, Consolitate.js alters the original object: https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/blob/master/lib/consolidate.js#L124

I've worked around this problem by always using a clone of partials:

```
// ...
var _ = require('underscore');

var partials = { layout: 'layout' };

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('index', { partials: _.clone(partials) });
});
```

It's not the best solution, but it works.

consolidate.js probably should use a different object for caching the partial content. And I managed to do this for hogan, but this wouldn't work with all the other engines.